# Is there any method to know that whether the data save offline is already synced online?

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, aws-appsync

I'm using aws appsync with react native and there is transaction happening offline and I want to know if mydata that is being transact offline is already saved in my db online.

The fetch policy I'm using is already network-only, but "network-only" policy is not working because it can still catch data if it is offline.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using DynamoDB with AppSync, you can add a condition expression to your mutation resolver request mapping template. DynamoDB conditions are used to validate whether the mutation should succeed or not.

Many people use versions with DynamoDB condition checks to validate that a record hasn't already been updated, but you can add additional fields to keep track of whether the transaction has already been made.

Here is an example condition expression that you can add to your request mapping template to validate the incoming mutation:

```
"condition" : {
    "expression"       : "version = :expectedVersion",
    "expressionValues" : {
        ":expectedVersion" : { "N" : ${context.arguments.expectedVersion} }
    }
}
```

Here is is an overly comprehensive guide to using DynamoDB resolvers:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorial-dynamodb-resolvers.html#modifying-the-updatepost-resolver-dynamodb-updateitem